# React creating folder structure with ubuntu command? which npm version using?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Iam trying to create react folder structure with npm version 8 but still error.
How to create react folder structure with Ubuntu command and which version using to npm and connect with mongodb database.Please help me....

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what do you want to do? It's not clear enough from question.

Comment: I need creating MERN project structure with ubuntu command..

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu command is not related to react. I use [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) package to create react app. Then I run `create-react-app myApp` and it creates my app